# Should we name it "Blog" or "Magazine"?

Tags: title, blog

We are an online travel agency. Ie a booking engine for accommodations and activities. We have a heavy content marketing strategy. We are in process of rebuilding our website. We're toying between calling our blog section the traditional "Blog" or something a bit different like "Magazine". Since a lot of our written blog-like content is very experiential, pretty photos, etc, that's where the fancy "Magazine" name comes from.

Whichever we choose will appear in the menu bar.

We have received some preliminary feedback from some of our older sales team saying if they saw "Magazine" in the menu bar they would not click on it because they would think it means subscribing to a magazine and "they don't want to do that".

What are peoples gut feel about this? 
Blog is well known, almost overused
Magazine is a bit more glamorous but not as well known title for blog section.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do your users think?

Comment: Have you considered other names, like travelogue, gazette, etc.? Blog sounds too informal, but magazine only brings to mind the printed medium and makes me think that the site is the online version of your printed magazine.

Answer (score 3):

How about calling it a **NewsStand**?

A newsstand is used to hold newspapers and magazines. Also, majority of the users are familiar with the term because of iOS' newsstand application which was dedicated to displaying digital versions of magazines and newspapers.

**Purpose of Blogs:**

> Blogs put more emphasis on a personal relationship between the writer
>   and readers. While both types on publications can have multiple
>   writers, bloggers usually emphasize engagement more than magazine
>   writers.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck with the Blog name. Since Blog as a name bring by default a comprehensive view of such a situation. Furthermore, usually 'Blogs' refereed to trustworthiness and accuracy of the contents that already have or that will be generated. Nevertheless, blogs now are more targeted by analytic people that may use your data in predicting a possible trend or to understand the current situation of your business.

Blogs also can be easily connected to other trusted blogs which gives the power to your platform to be scalable and reliable. Hope that answer the question.